# Rails 4 devise gem: How to show number of remaining login attempts to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise gem and want to show number of remaining attempts if login failed to the user.i searched the entire document but didn't find any solutions.

Below is my session_controller.rb file

```
  def create
    unless captcha_valid? params[:captcha]
      flash[:error] = "Invalid Captcha"
      redirect_to new_user_session_url
      return false
    else
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In devise if you are making the user `lockable` then a column is added `failed_attempts` which shows the user's failed attempts. This column is set to zero when a user successfully logs in. And in the `devise.rb` file you specify the number of attempts you are providing the user. So just subtract both of them and that would be the remaining attempts. The default number of attempts is 20 I think but not sure.

Comment: To avoid hard-coding the number in your logic, Devise exposes a `maximum_attempts` method.  So you can do something like `remaining = Devise.maximum_attempts - user.failed_attempts`